# Getting a "Type mismatch (Error 13)" when Delete data in target column

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

First off I want to say that I have zero experience with any of this. I just discovered vba two days ago because of my google searches and it led me to this site which has been extremly helpful.

I have a vba code/function(dont know what to call it, sorry) that I used from here and slightly modified to work for what I wanted to do.
Right now it does exactly what I want except for when I clear out the cells that have information in them it gives me an error 13 type mismatch. I don't think there is any way around this but like I said, I know nothing at all about what I am doing.

Here is my current code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 16 And Target.Value = "Complete" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now())
    End If
End Sub
```

In a shared "data tracking sheet" In column 16 I have data validation, select from a list, with a dropdown box to select "Complete". With my current code when I select Complete in the dropdown box it generates the date in the column next to the drop down box. This is all working as intended.

If you were to delete the drop down box selection of "completed" and adjacent column with the date, it gives me the error 13. If I hit end on the error message it goes away and everything functions as it should. This is only a problem if someone were to accidentally mark the wrong box as completed then delete what they have done, but all they have to do is hit end on the error message and it goes away and works properly.

Is there any way around this or will everyone that accesses this data tracking sheet just have to know to hit end if this error message pops up?

I apologize in advance if this is a poorly worded question.

As of now I am not sure what to try to solve this problem, or if it can be solved.

Comment: Put `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` at the beginning.

Comment: Amazing, this took care of my problem. Thank you so much!